# Thymeleaf Page Layouts

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am trying use thymeleaf page layouts in my current spring-boot project.

template resources/templates/common/menu.html

```
 <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="menu" oncontextmenu='return false' ondragstart='return false' onmousedown='return false'>
        <div class="pure-menu">
            <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="index.html">
                <img src="../../../images/home.png" width="136" height="43" alt="SL" />
            </a>
    ..
</div>
</div>
```

on my index.html:

```
<div oncontextmenu='return false' ondragstart='return false' onmousedown='return false' th:include="common/menu :: [//div[@id='menu']]"></div>
```

and this is the result of doing view source on the HTML page

```
 <div>
        <div class="pure-menu">
            <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="index.html">
                <img src="../../../images/home.png" width="136" height="43" alt="SL" />
            </a>
```

The attributes of the  tag has dissapeared

Comment: may be th:replace will solve your problem.

Comment: @TanmoyMandal, please convert to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be th:replace will solve your problem.